# How to show Touch Keyboard when mouse is connected?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, keyboard, mouse, windows-10

When I have my bluetooth mouse connected to my Windows 10 Surface 3, the Touch Keyboard does not appear if I click into a textbox with the mouse. The keyboard only comes up if I tap the screen (the textbox) with my finger. I just want to use the tablet with a mouse and the Touch Keyboard.

So my question is: how can I make the Touch Keyboard come up when I click a textbox with my mouse, WITHOUT having to tap the box?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do that manually. Check the code example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921638/332528